# Is there any way to flatten a nested ifdef structure in WiX?

Tags: wix

I'm using a nested ifdef structure in WiX like the following:

```
<?ifdef a?>
    ...
<?else?>
    <?ifdef b?>
        ...
    <?else?>
        <?ifdef c?>
            ...
        <?else?>
            ...
        <?endif?>
    <?endif?>
<?endif>
```

Is there any way(syntax?) to transform this into something like:

```
<?ifdef a?>
    ...
<?else ifdef b?>
    ...
<?else ifdef c?>
    ...
<?else?>
    ...
<?endif>
```

Comment: This is something I'm looking for as well, to use with giving different build configurations different names.

Answer (score 0):

WIX toolset feature request http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4767/ asks for a new pre-processor function $(fun.defined(X)), which returns true if variable X is defined.  If and when this feature is implemented you could flatten the nested `<?ifdef ... ?>` structure as follows:

```
<?if $(fun.defined(a)) ?>
...
<?elif $(fun.defined(b)) ?>
...
<?elif $(fun.defined(c)) ?>
...
<?else?>
...
<?endif>
```

Admittedly this isn't an answer that works today, but it might be worth lobbying for the WIX feature request if important.